# Finding the `/` character as a separator using regexp as for phrases wrapped and not wrapped by other `/` characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regexp that can find occurrences of `/` from a string however the following rules must be satisfied:

- `/` is a separator between each string, e.g: /string1/string2/string3/
- The `/` is also a separator between regular expressions like /regexp1//regexp2//regexp3/

The goal is to find all occurrences of the separator `/` that satisfy such a condition
[image]

As a result, I would like to get the separators between the following phrases

- `string1`
- `string2`
- `string3`
- `/regexp1/`
- `/regexp2/`
- `/regexp3/`
- `string4`

```
/string1/string2/string3//regexp1///regexp2///regexp3//string4/
```

Currently I prepared the following regexp, but unfortunately it doesn't work as I expect, because it doesn't handle when there are 2 regexps next to each other. Does anyone have any advice how to overcome such case?

`((?<=\/)\/(?=\/)|(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)|(?<=\w)\/(?=\/)|(?<=\/)\/(?=\w)|\/$)`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with an alternation and grab **capture group #1**:

```
(?<=\/)(\/[^\/]+\/|[^\/]+)(?:\/|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV7Hpf/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\/)`: Assert that previous character is `/`
- `(` Start capture group #1

  - `\/`: Match a `/`
  - [^/]+`: Match 1+ non-`/` characters
  - `\/`: Match a `/`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^\/]+`: Match 1+ non-`/` characters
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(?:\/|$)`: Match a `/` or end position

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's almost working like I would like, but when I add a `/regexp4/` at the end of the text then string4 is also parsed as `/string4/.

Comment: What is your full input line now?

Comment: `/string1/string2/string3//regexp1///regexp2///regexp3//string4//regexp4/`
The previous one was an example, but i could be great if it will support `string` and `/regexp/` at the end of the line

Comment: Or else if trailing `/` is optional then you can use: `(?<=\/)\/[^\/]+\/(?=\/|$)|[^\/]+`

Comment: Yes, trailing `/` is optional but using `(?<=\/)\/[^\/]+\/(?=\/|$)|[^\/]+` with `/string1/string2/string3//regexp1///regexp2///regexp3//string4//regexp4//` or `/string1/string2/string3//regexp1///regexp2///regexp3//string4//regexp4/` it parses `string4` as `/string4/`



Output: `["string1", "string2", "string3", "/regexp1/", "/regexp2/", "/regexp3/", "/string4/", "/regexp4/"]`

Comment: ok check my updated answer. You need to grab capture group #1

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Now it works as I expected.